# Passing variable from controller to view page shows undefined variable in Yii2

Tags: web, web-applications, yii2, parameter-passing, yii2-basic-app

I'm very new to Yii2 Framework. I want to pass variable from controller to view.

In controller:

```
public function actionDeleteAll(){
    $var1 = 'abc';
    return $this->redirect(array('index', 'var_view' => $var1 ));
}
```

In view:

```
<?php  
    echo $_GET['var_view'];
?>
```

But page show:

[image]

Comment: You have redirected to index action, add index action code also. You want to render `view` page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `render()` instead of `redirect()`.

```
public function actionDeleteAll() {
    $var1 = 'abc';
    return $this->render('index', ['var_view' => $var1]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you really want a redirect to  index  .. passing the value in $var1 as var_view

```
public function actionDeleteAll(){
  $var1 = 'abc';
  return $this->redirect(array('index', 'var_view' => $var1 ));
}
```

be sure that your index  have a proper signature eg:

```
public function actionIndex($var_view)
{
     .... your code  .. 

    return $this->render('index', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'var_view' => $var_view 
    ]);
}
```

redirect work as function call so you must pass  the proper param with corresponding param 
name